# What's the best way to center an SVG horizontally and vertically inside a div tag?

Tags: html, svg, centering

What's the best way to center an SVG horizontally and vertically an SVG inside a div tag?

I know some ways are better than others, but for this what would be the best way of doing it?

```html
    <div style="width: 64px;height: 64px;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 24px;background-position: 58% 50%;border-radius: 500px;border: 1px solid blue;cursor: pointer;">
        
        <svg viewBox="-22 0 1229 1481" width="24" height="29" style="display:block;margin: 0 auto;background-color:green;">
        <path d="M0 1394V87C0 46.3 13.3 19.8 40 7.5 66.7-4.8 98.7.3 136 23l1034 634c37.3 22.7 56 50.3 56 83s-18.7 60.3-56 83L136 1458c-37.3 22.7-69.3 27.8-96 15.5-26.7-12.3-40-38.8-40-79.5z" fill="red"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on setting fixed positions, pixel sizes and margins yourself, just adjust the svg vertical margin.

```html
    <div style="width: 64px;height: 64px;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 24px;background-position: 58% 50%;border-radius: 500px;border: 1px solid blue;cursor: pointer;">
        
        <svg viewBox="-22 0 1229 1481" width="24" height="29" style="display:block;margin:16px auto;background-color:green;">
        <path d="M0 1394V87C0 46.3 13.3 19.8 40 7.5 66.7-4.8 98.7.3 136 23l1034 634c37.3 22.7 56 50.3 56 83s-18.7 60.3-56 83L136 1458c-37.3 22.7-69.3 27.8-96 15.5-26.7-12.3-40-38.8-40-79.5z" fill="red"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css style for your SVG element

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
```

and this css for DIV element

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
```